# Why do I get different SUM values when I use OVER (PARTITION BY yearValue)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Yellow table is **raw_data**, and green table is **desired_output**

[image]

When I use the following code I get the green table above

```
SELECT Year, Country, sum(pageViews) total_pageviews
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY Year, Country
```

However, when I try to partition by `Year` I get lower numbers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, Country, SUM(pageViews) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) 
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY Year, Country, pageViews
```

So the output looks like this 
[image]
Any idea why this happens when using `PARTITION BY`?

Comment: What is the actual result that you expect?

Comment: desired_output - i.e. the green box using `SUM(pageViews) OVER (PARTITION BY Year)`

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use a window function, while you do get the results that you expect with aggregation?

Comment: I don't believe you when you say that your second query gives the last set of results.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0b16/3  Please edit with ***actual*** input and ***actual*** output to demonstrate what you want and what you get.  Then explain what you ***think*** adding `OVER (PARTITION BY Year)` should do *(and why you added `, pageViews` to the `GROUP BY`, but didn't mention it?)*  Because, at present, your first query ***appears*** to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Your edit to add `DISTINCT` along with the `GROUP BY` just shows that you're not sure what you're asking.  Please, reframe the question with ***actual*** example input and ***actual*** desired results.

Comment: Basically I was wondering why doesn't  `SUM(pageViews) OVER (PARTITION BY Year)` give the same results as using the GROUP BY. The data above is just an example, my table has thousands of rows. I forgot to add 'DISTINCT` as without it, it produces multiple rows

Comment: Even with the Distinct it doesn't give the results you assert that it does...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0b16/4

Comment: It's an example dude - "So the output looks something like this" - I can't post my entire table.

Comment: This shows what you're doing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0b16/6

Comment: This shows what SO says you should do to ask a question that doesn't just confuse the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're right, I apologize - the desired solution is vague. I'll edit when I'm in work tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `PageViews` in the `GROUP BY`, so your code is not actually aggregating.  That is the root of your problem.

Instead, you seem to be trying for:

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM(SUM(pageViews)) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) 
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY Year, Country;
```

But you actually want a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM(pageViews)
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY Year, Country;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is actually possible outside of using a subquery. `partition by` doesn't change the number of rows returned like `group by` does and because of that your code still returns a line for each data entry. You can't remove `pageViews` from the `group by` without receiving an error - because again, `partition by` doesn't actually change the number of rows in the results so you are required to include `pageViews` in your `group by` which returns incorrect results.

Running the `partition by` without your `group by`

```
SELECT [year]  AS [year],
       Country AS Country,    
       SUM(pageViews) OVER(PARTITION BY [year]) AS Total
from raw_data
```

will return:

```
Year    Country Total
2018    US      15
2018    US      15
2019    US      30
2019    US      30
2019    US      30
2019    US      30
```

Selecting the results of the partition query and then grouping will solve this:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT [year]  AS [year],
       Country AS Country,    
       SUM(pageViews) OVER(PARTITION BY [year]) AS Total
from raw_data
) as outer_query
group by outer_query.[year], outer_query.Country, outer_query.Total
```

but I'm with GMB in questioning why you would need to do something like this when a simple aggregate will suffice.

-**edit**- While my answer will get you correct results, it's best not to do work arounds if there is a more practical solution. Gordon has the correct way to implement this - that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The last query is not only "odd", it's asking the server to do potentially massive amounts of extra work *(as BigQuery normally works on BigData)*.  I'm also not particularly convinced that it makes sense; every country will have the same total; the total for that year across all countries.

Comment: @MatBailie Good catch, added "Country" to the `Partition By` statement which will fix that issue. Regardless, this would be a bad approach in any case. I was going to delete my answer, but it was already accepted. Gordon's would be the correct solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was really just trying to understand why `SUM(pageViews) OVER (PARTITION BY Year)` wasn't giving me the same answer as `GROUP BY`. Understood now.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Your first query is the most correct way to get the result you expect

But,  if for whatever reason you want Analytic function to be involved (as in your second query) - you should use below version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Year, Country, SUM(SUM(pageViews)) OVER(PARTITION BY Year, Country) total_pageviews
FROM `project.dataset.raw_data`
GROUP BY Year, Country
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your `GROUP BY`, since you want total of pageview then you don't need to include it :

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM(pageViews) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) AS total_pageviews
FROM raw_data
GROUP BY Year, Country;
```

So, `total_pageviews` will be based on `Year` regardless of `Country`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, theres no use of `partition by` simultaneously with the `group by` in your query. Group by and partition by are most or all the time are used seperately.

It depends on the usage meaning if you want all your rows to be identified as groups with no effect on the reduction of rows with aggregates we use partition by clause but if you want to have groups and with reduction of rows with aggregates go for a group by.

Usually it happens to be the case when you have a lot of columns and you wanna perform aggregation you go for partition by but thats not always unless all the columns with aggregates fall in sync you could go for group by

`Group by` reduces the number of rows on aggregates

```
  SELECT Year, Country, sum(pageViews) 
  total_pageviews
  FROM raw_data
  GROUP BY Year, Country
```

While `partition by` gives all rows

```
  SELECT Year, Country, sum(pageViews) 
  Over (partition by year, country order 
   by year, country) 
   total_pageviews
  FROM raw_data
```

Try to run these 2 queries separately n see the difference